# How to use Many To Many relation with 3 fields in symfony4

Tags: symfony, many-to-many

I have 3 tables Users(name, email), Groups(group_name), Contacts(name, email) :-
- Currently I have many-to-many relation between Groups and Users where  i can add multiple users in a group
- Now what i want is that i will able to add Contacts as well as Users in Groups.

> For Example if i create a group with name "Group 1" then i will able
>   to add "User 1", "User 2", "Contact 1", "Contact 2", "User 3" in that
>   group.

Something like this:-

````
<table>
    <tr><th>Group_id</th><th>User_id</th><th>Contact_id</th></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>Null</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1 </td><td>3</td><td>Null</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1 </td><td>Null</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>```
Help me with this if anyone has solution.
````

Comment: if the contact and user don't appear together*, it's IMHO better to just make two relations group<->contact, and group<->user. *if there is no semantic necessity for them to appear together, don't force it.

Comment: did you mean i have make 2 manytomany relations?

Comment: you don't have to. but I would do so, if I were in your shoes. doctrine itself has no many-to-many between three entities, you theoretically could also make the relation itself an entity (which then would have many-to-one to all three entities, with nullable true or something), but there's no apparent necessity to do that (also inheritance mapping, which almost always is a nightmare)

Comment: ok i have sloved this by creating a new entity with 3 ManyToOne relation one with Group, User and Contact

Answer (score 0):

I take that the (main/only) difference between a user and a contact is that the first has a password field or similar to log into your system. Then I can only think of as alternative that contacts have only a relationship with specific users (whoever creates the contact), in a private contacts fashion for a specific user (who can choose to share his/her contacts with the world). For your table with three fields, just in case you want to add a user to a contact group, the contact_id would be null or zero, to indicate it's the "owning" user. Not a clean solution after all.

Another way would be to share the same table for both users and contacts, with a "type" field to act as a switch for identifying if it's a user or a contact, or just by taking the password field if it's empty to identify a contact. In this case, you just need the id of the table and can get rid of the contact_id for the contact groups table.